# The color of selected item on AngularJS disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I need the color of the selected item not to disappear after I click any other part of the page.

Index.html

> ```
> <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-collapse-bottom-right navbar-collapse-default">
>     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-bottom-right">
>         <li class="menuitem" ng-repeat="item in menu"><a href="/#!/{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a>
>         </li>
>     </ul>
> </div>
> ```

app.js

> $rootScope.menu = [
>           {
>               title: 'Product',
>               url: 'product'
>           },
>           {
>               title: 'About',
>               url: 'about'
>           },
>           {
>               title: 'Contact',
>               url: 'contact'
>           },
>           {
>               title: 'Register',
>               url: 'register'
>           },
>           {
>               title: 'Login',
>               url: 'login'
>           }
>       ];

I add this code but he don't work

```
 App.controller('MainController', function ($scope, $rootScope) {  
 $scope.isActive = function(item) {
     return $scope.selected === item; };
         $rootScope.menu = [
             {
                 title: 'Product',
                 url: 'product'
             },
             {
                 title: 'About',
                 url: 'about'
             },
             {
                 title: 'Contact',
                 url: 'contact'
             },
             {
                 title: 'Register',
                 url: 'register'
             },
             {
                 title: 'Login',
                 url: 'login'
             }
         ];

 });
```

problem unresolved

Comment: what color, what selected item? explain it more please

Comment: example - is active: red; is inactive: blue.

Comment: set ng-class=active when you click on an item

Comment: did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: updated my answer let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok so this is how I have made an item that is generated using ng-repeat to be "selected" aka active.

I set the ng-class"active" by doing below.

Hope this helps

```
 <div class="panel-body" id="repeate">
                <div class="list-group" ng-show="Song.length > 0" ng-repeat="s in Song | orderBy: 'Date' :true | limitTo: 100">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-class="{active: isActive(s)}" ng-click="select(s)">{{s.SongName}}</a>
                </div>
 </div>
```

JS to add

```
  $scope.select = function(i) {
    $scope.selected = i;
  };
    $scope.isActive = function(item) {
        return $scope.selected === item;
    };
```